# PHP Zend, Facebook Share Option

Tags: php, facebook

I want to create a facebook share option after payment is succeeded. I am trying to develop a simple website that is coded in PHP with Zend Framework. Can you advice me something or give me reference that i can look to. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default share functionality is considered deprecated by facebook itself. You can read about this here: [Facebook Developers - Share](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/)

The suggested method is to implement the current version of the Like-button of which you can read about more on this page: [Facebook Developers - Like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

You'll find lots of information on the page itself. To get started, you should read yourself into [Facebook Developers - PHP SDK Overview](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

PS: Pretty unreliant to Zend Framework itself :)